# Can`t get results from my database (class PDF extends)

Tags: php, pdf

class PDF extends

Can`t get results from my database into my class PDF extends.

I have done several tests but unfortunately without success.

How can I get the results from: `$users[post_id]`?

```
// Logo
$this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
// Arial bold 15
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
// Move to the right
$this->Cell(80);
// Title
$this->Cell(30,10,'{$users[post_id]}',1,0,'C');
// Line break
$this->Ln(20);
```

Comment: Please try using global ( $GLOBALS['variablename'] ) to pass the variable to the pdf generator

Comment: Ken Lee I trying    $this->Cell(30,10,'$GLOBALS[post_id]',1,0,'C');
but still non result  ????

Comment: On further question - are you using TCPDF (or fPDF ?) or other module ?

Comment: I using FPDF  & factly it is simple just the results from this code

<?php 
  
include('connection.php');

$id = (int) $_GET['id'];

$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `w3_post` WHERE post_id='" . $id . "' ");
$users=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
?>

Comment: If you use hardcode (say put "ABC" instead of {$users[post_id]}, what will happen ? (sorry because I do not use fPDF so I cannot try your codes).

Comment: Sorry for my late comment where out with my dog,,,,
If I just do how you say I getting normal result like ABC

When I put I see the same in output {$users[post_id]}

Comment: Halfer is this all you could do edit my writing ????   smartguy

Comment: if you can $users[post_id] to $users["post_id"], what will happen ?

Comment: Ken Lee I did that already but nothing happens I just see the same how it is written $users["post_id"]

Comment: I even tried with the string like this {$users["post_id"]}

Comment: Please change '{$users[post_id]}'     to (1) $users[post_id]   or  (2)  $users["post_id"]  . I mean remove {, } and all ' marks

Comment: All those doesn`t give any results ?   so strange

Comment: If you type "ABC" and the system can use ABC as print out in the cell, if means the fPDF is working . The only problem is your variable  $users["post_id"] does not get passed. Is it true that you are using a function to enclose the fPDF print-out ??

Comment: The script I put toghether is mutch longer in other parts what begins with $pdf->Write it is working normaly.... Further the script total is working normal but I don`t known mutch from it

Comment: I dropped some scripts together here on this address is a show-up
http://145.53.93.209/Molendijk//pdf/?id=1115

Comment: I cannot find the scripts. (just see the pdf)

Comment: did you fix the problem ?

Comment: Ken lee I gave up I gonna try do something else with the title....
Sorry for the late answer & thanks for all the support

The URL should work meight the second you checkt I where busy ????